# removing intersecting geometry in blender 2.9

Tags: modifiers

In blender 2.79 we could use the boolean carve solver to just keep the meshes on the outer surface, eg:
this:
[image]
could be maintained to this:

[image]

but, the carve solver was dropped since 2.8. Does anyone have any workaround or technique to achieve this in blender > 2.8?(*except for*  the remeshing in blender sculpt mode, which is destructive as well as requires too much density to cover the details)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean modifier, with "difference" or "union" to join them
[image]

it also worked in 2.9

Comment: this works only if the two meshes are separate, if the two meshes have some vertices merged, then this doesn't work. E.g. try joining the two spheres > Ctrl+J , and merge at least one vertex, then removing the intersecting geometry like this(Union or difference) doesn't work, but it used to work with boolean modifier's carve solver, back in 2.79 days. :-(

Comment: @juztcode Hmm.. I'm not sure there's a proper way to do that besides remesh, using remesh will surely destroy the mesh

Comment: yeah, the algorithm is not doing a good job at that, the carve was however acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cikitta Tjok is right. You can use the **Boolean Modifier** and select **Union**.

[image]

If you like, in the viewport you can go to *Object -> Apply -> Visual Geometry to Mesh*.

[image]

This way you can apply the modifier on the mesh and "bake" it. This step makes both sides of the mesh editable for weight painting, for example.

[image]

Comment: This "visual geometry to mesh" only applies the modifier stack it seems. And the union operator of the bool. mod. only works if the two meshes are separate, if the two meshes have some vertices merged, then this doesn't work. E.g. try joining the two spheres > Ctrl+J , and merge at least one vertex, then removing the intersecting geometry like this(Union or difference) doesn't work, but it used to work with boolean modifier's carve solver, back in 2.79 days. :-(